# Attempt to read property "currentTeam" on null

Tags: laravel, null, laravel-jetstream

can you help me?... I got the error when I wanted to reset my password with jetstream. do you know how to fix the error? I've been confused with this error.. please help me, thanks for your feedback...

ErrorException
Attempt to read property "currentTeam" on null (View: D:\Project\inventory-web\resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset

Answer (score -1):

you are logouted. back to Login page of your application, and login again.